# Cython - Passing a method always leeds to compilation failure

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to rewrite my app to cython. Now I stucked when I try pass my cdef method as argument to another. I always become error:  Cannot convert 'f_type' to Python object - by compilation but here is my code:

CrossValMethods.pxd:

```
cdef class CrossValMethods:
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    cdef list flatCrossVal(self, list items, int numberOfFolds, graph, int nrOfNodes,
                  defaultClassMat, int lbpSteps, float lbpThreshold, object k_fold_cross_validation,
                  object separationMethod, object lbp, list layerWeights, isRandomWalk, object adjMatPrep,
                  object prepareLayers, object prepareClassMat)
```

CrossValMethods.pyx:

```
cdef class CrossValMethods:
'''
classdocs
'''


    def __cinit__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''

    cdef list flatCrossVal(self, list items, int numberOfFolds, graph, int nrOfNodes,
                  defaultClassMat, int lbpSteps, float lbpThreshold, object k_fold_cross_validation,
                  object separationMethod, object lbp, list layerWeights, isRandomWalk, object adjMatPrep,
                  object prepareLayers, object prepareClassMat):
    ...
    code
    ...
```

This compiles normally

LPBTools.pxd:

```
cimport graph.method.lbp.CrossValMethods as cvm
ctypedef list (*f_type)(cvm.CrossValMethods, list, int, object, int, object, int, float, object, object, object, list, object, object, object, object)
cdef class LBPTools:
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    cdef list crossVal(self, items, numberOfFolds, graph, nrOfNodes,
                 defaultClassMat, lbpSteps, lbpThreshold,
                 k_fold_cross_validation, separationMethod, lbp, layerWeights, f_type crossValMethod, isRandomWalk, adjMarPrep, prepareLayers, prepareClassMat)
```

LBPTools.pyx:

```
cdef class LBPTools:
    def __cinit__(self):
    '''
    Constructor
    '''
    cdef list crossVal(self, items, numberOfFolds, graph, nrOfNodes,
                 defaultClassMat, lbpSteps, lbpThreshold, 
                 k_fold_cross_validation, separationMethod, lbp, layerWeights, f_type crossValMethod, isRandomWalk, adjMarPrep, prepareLayers, prepareClassMat):
        return crossValMethod(cvm.CrossValMethods(), items, numberOfFolds, graph, nrOfNodes,
                 defaultClassMat, lbpSteps, lbpThreshold, k_fold_cross_validation, separationMethod, lbp, layerWeights, isRandomWalk, adjMarPrep, prepareLayers, prepareClassMat)
```

This also compiles succesfully, but

FlatLBP.pxd:

```
cimport graph.method.lbp.CrossValMethods as cvm
ctypedef list (*f_type)(cvm.CrossValMethods, list, int, object, int, object, int, float, object, object, object, list, object, object, object, object)
cdef class FlatLBP:
```

FlatLBP.pyx:

```
ctypedef list (*f_type)(crossValMethods.CrossValMethods, list, int, object, int, object, int, float, object, object, object, list, object, object, object, object)
cdef class FlatLBP:

    def __cinit__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
    cdef list start(self, graph, int nrOfNodes, np.ndarray defaultClassMat, int nrOfClasses, int lbpSteps, float lbpThreshold, int numberOfFolds):


        cdef list fold_sum = []
        cdef int i
        for i in range(1,nrOfNodes+1,1):
            fold_sum.append([i,0,0])


        cdef int fold_number = 1
        cdef list items = range(nrOfNodes)
        cdef float timer = time.time()

        cdef np.ndarray fuz_mean_occ = np.array([])

        cdef crossValMethods.CrossValMethods method = crossValMethods.CrossValMethods()
        cdef f_type methodToPass = method.flatCrossVal
        lbp = LoopyBeliefPropagation()
        #TODO add tzpe when changed to cdef class
        tools = tool.LBPTools(nrOfNodes, graph, defaultClassMat, lbpSteps, lbpThreshold)

        fold_sum = tools.crossVal(items, numberOfFolds, graph, nrOfNodes, 
                   defaultClassMat, lbpSteps, lbpThreshold, 
                   tools.k_fold_cross_validation, self.prepareFoldClassMat,
                   lbp.lbp, None, methodToPass, False, None, None, None)
```

Here compilation failes with error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
    tools = tool.LBPTools(nrOfNodes, graph, defaultClassMat, lbpSteps, lbpThreshold)

    fold_sum = tools.crossVal(items, numberOfFolds, graph, nrOfNodes,
                   defaultClassMat, lbpSteps, lbpThreshold,
                   tools.k_fold_cross_validation, self.prepareFoldClassMat,
                   lbp.lbp, None, methodToPass, False, None, None, None)
                                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

FlatLBP.pyx:66:50: Cannot convert 'f_type' to Python object
```

Ok I know that notation is horrible and code is very messy. 
I only want to know is there way to pass cdef method as parameter or always it will be converted to python object? If there is way, what I'm doing wrong? 
I will be very gratefull for any help.
I do not have any experience in C, I'm mainly Java guy and somebody ask me to use python and then  cython.

Regards,
Adrian

Comment: is this module `tools` designed by you? It seems it accepts only Python functions, such that you will have to use the normal `def` functions. Perhaps with `cpdef` functions it will work, but not with `cdef`...